# Recommendations for a mechanical or traditional keyboard? Which is better?

Tags: keyboards

I'm wondering what the advantages of using mechanical keyboards vs. traditional keyboards (i.e. membrane keyboards) are.

My primary uses will be coding, productivity, and avoiding getting RSI.

Comment: As per anything it depends on what you consider an upside. PC World has a good [post](http://www.pcworld.com/article/240939/mechanical_keyboards_should_you_switch_.html) on the subject that may be worth taking a look at.

Comment: I have had an issue in the past with coding in a work environment (cubes) and using mechanical due to the noise level annoying coworkers. Is this a potential concern to you?

Comment: @Gram Noise isn't too much of an issue for me, but they can indeed ne quite loud, I agree

Comment: VTC: Atwood's blog covered this in excruciating detail :)

Comment: @DVK http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-code-keyboard/ ? a bit too wordy though :)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - Yes

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In my experience (new mechanical user):

**Advantages**

- Key Rollover - Mechanical keyboards should support NKRO (infinite simultaneous key presses) over PS/2 and 6KRO (six simultaneous key presses not including four modifiers like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, etc., so 10 simultaneous) over USB*. Being able to press this many keys means the only limit to your typing speed is your fingers, not the keyboard.
- Repair/Customisation - Keycaps are easy to remove so you can move them around (mine is Colemak. I've also heard good things about Workman). Also this means replacing keys and cleaning are a lot easier than on many non-mechanicals.
- Build quality - As a premium product the build quality and reliability is very high. As an example the standard [Cherry MX switches](http://cherrycorp.com/product/mx-series/) can withstand 50 million key presses compared to 5-10 from rubber dome keys.
- Feel - There is something nice about the key presses of a mechanical keyboard

*Specifically a limitation of the USB protocol. This may be manufacturer specific, but I'm not sure. If anyone knows, comment below!

**Aesthetics**

For many people the aesthetics are important. If you spend a lot of money on something you often want it too look good. With my keyboard free custom keycaps and printing were included so mine looks like this:

[image: We do what we must because we can]

**Disadvantages**

Cost is significantly higher than a normal keyboard (mine was US$200 approximately).

Comment: I would also add in the ability to make them quieter by placing O-rings on the keys. At work, I have MX-Clear with red O-rings (from wasdkeyboards) and it is only slightly louder than rubber dome keyboards. Also, nice StarFox coffee mug.

Comment: As an advantage or disadvantage? I wonder if that is better left as an addendum of useful info (which would improve the post to be sure). Much as I enjoy the sound of my keyboard and might get o-rings in the future volume might well be a disadvantage in office situations.

Comment: I would say an advantage, because no one is forcing you to install the O-rings. I got the O-rings (and clear switches) to make it as quiet as possible for work environments. If noise is wanted, than you have the options of green or blue switches (which I use at home).

Comment: Are you suggesting I extend the customisability section?

Comment: It should be fine to leave it in the comments. It is a rather small part to consider when buying a mechanical keyboard.

Comment: Regarding key rollover, might want to consider my question [In what way does non-“full n-key rollover” hinder fast typists?](http://superuser.com/q/762611/53590) (unfortunately currently closed as opinion-based) on [su].

Comment: We might want to make a community wiki guide on mechanical keyboards.

Answer (score 10):

If you're just coding and avoiding RSI, get a keyboard with [scissor switches](http://deskthority.net/wiki/Scissor_switch). This switch type is used in the famous ultra-thin Apple keyboard and most modern laptops. It's extremely quiet so you won't get annoyed, and its key feature is its low profile meaning you don't have to press keys down "really far."

With a mechanical keyboard, most switch types need the user to press 3-4 mm (from initial to actuation point), which doesn't seem like much at all, but after a ton of key presses it adds up quickly. Scissor switches reduce this distance to just 1-2 mm.

You definitely want a keyboard with scissor switches if you're just coding.

Comment: I've been coding for about ten years and scissor switch keyboards have failed me a lot in the past. Keys broke or came loose, silicon wore down, sensors broke, etc.

Comment: Isn't the actuation *force* a more interesting metric than depth of keypress? Back when mechanical typewriters were a thing, people would have *killed* for a 3-4 mm actuation depth...

Comment: Can't you get 2 mm of travel distance by adding o-rings in a mechanical keyboard?

Comment: @Franck It's possible, but the raised keys of a mechanical keyboard will keep your hands at an unnatural raised angle (assuming you don't use a big wrist rest) while a keyboard with scissor switches allows your hands to lay almost completely flat.

Comment: @Adam: Actually I had planned to use a big wrist rest :)